# Blade template code formatting issue in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-blade, code-formatting

I am using PhpStorm 8.0.3 and Blade Templating (using Laravel) and when I reformat code it gets really nasty

> [image]

[**full tab image after disabling blade plugin and formatting**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awEvU.png)

[**full tab image with blade plugin enable**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b69ne.png)

I tried possible solutions described at the [Jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24357#comment=27-804192) which didnt work

Does anyone have any idea why this happening?

Comment: 1) Try resetting code style to a default/predefined one (use `Set From` while on "PHP" node and choose the most desired one) 2) Right now it does not look like it's a HTML code at all -- please show a screenshot of **whole** editor tab.

Comment: tried but still same result

Comment: @LazyOne here is full tab image http://i.stack.imgur.com/awEvU.png

Comment: **First of all:** blade files should have different file icon -- right now it's just an ordinary php file and not blade file (in eyes of IDE, of course). Make sure that `*.blade.php` pattern is associated with `Blade` in `Settings | Editor | File Types`

Comment: **Secondly:** (if #1 will not fix it) -- you seems to have some wrong language injected somewhere in your code which treats the rest of the file as wrong file type/language. Please show your `Settings | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: @LazyOne i tired disable it and enable but not working let me get  you image after enabling blade plugin

Comment: @LazyOne http://i.stack.imgur.com/b69ne.png , thanks checking code for wrong language injection

Comment: So .. did you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: @LazyOne  still not , though for now using netbeans ,

Comment: So .. if you are still interested -- please show screenshot of your Language Injections settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74709/discussion-between-nullpoite-and-lazyone).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for you help .. though its quite late replay from me :( ... i just updated phpstorm and it works fine.. btw you have got gold badge in phpstorm tag ... holy cow

Answer (score -1):

I write all the `PHP, HTML, Blade` code in `phpstorm2020.1`, and sometimes in `VSCode` too. I saw major difference how these two IDE's format code. Sometimes `PHPStorm` does not format the blade very well, you have to go to the `Settings` by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + S`, then `Editor -> Code Style`, here you will find `PHP` and `Blade` format settings, do some stuff with the settings and make your own settings. Whenever you'll install a newer version, all the settings will be migrate to latest version. Obviously `PHPStorm` is much powerful but `VSCode` formats the `blade` very well. You can install `Prettier` plugin too to for the proper formatting.

Even latest `phpstorm2022.1`, sometimes it won't format the code properly when the code is big, it mis-aligns the `@directives` and content into the `directives` etc when pressing `CTRL + ALT + L`.

I then stackoverflowed the solution, tried to install `Prettier` via `NPM` but it does not the same as I want.